# How to write Bootstrap Autocloseable alert msg in Repsonse.Write in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Code as follow
Login.aspx.cs file

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Response.Write("<script>alert('Login Sucessfully');</script>"); //how to write bootstrap above code in it.
 Response.Redirect("~/Admin/frmAdminHome.aspx");
}
```

I want to write bootstrap autoclosable alert msg in Response.Write 
Bootstrap code as

```
<div id="alertdiv" class="alert ' + alerttype + '"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><span>' + message + '</span></div>
```

Comment: You can use `ClientScript` for both alert and redirection to the next page.

Comment: Can you give me example of it? @Nadeem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is just an example of what you can do.**

You can do something like below.

```
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Alert worked succesfully');window.location ='Admin/frmAdminHome.aspx';", true);
}
```

try the code as per your requirement

Comment: the url doesn't forward to next page , and how to write the above bootstrap code  in your code , could you explain ? @Nadeem

Comment: It Gives error like this Requested URL: /Visitors/~/Admin/frmAdminHome.aspx .The resource cannot be found. @Nadeem

Comment: Path and folder are correct . The file is in that folder, the link work with Response.Redirect("~/Admin/frmAdminHome.aspx"); Your code gives above error and cannot redirect to that page. @Nadeem

Comment: Yeah the above updated code i have tried it. Still it gives same error. @Nadeem

Comment: Code as follow.  protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Your alert worked');window.location ='~/Admin/frmAdminHome.aspx';", true);} @Nadeem

Comment: still above updated code doesn't work.Give error . Error are Server Error in '/' Application. , The resource cannot be found. , Requested URL: /Visitors/Admin/frmAdminHome.aspx @Nadeem

Comment: Still code does't work , your above comment i copied it  and paste it, but same thing happen . Infact this time it has given error :Requested URL: /Visitors/Visitors/Admin/frmAdminHome.aspx @Nadeem